# Return URL in PayPal in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have written a PHP code. When a user submits the form, it saves all information in session and redirect user to PayPal Payment page. When user successfully makes Payment, Paypal sends user to Return path. The return path page gets values from session and enter user in database. But, after submitting the form if user manually visit Return path URL, it will save information in database without getting payment. Any solution for this?

Comment: Please show your code. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing your code, it's difficult to give an accurate answer, but based upon what you've provided...

Paypal allows you to provide 2 URLs to it's submission, a return_url and a notify_url.

With the return_url, it should be for display only (e.g. www.website.com/order_complete/), and should NEVER have any functionality behind it, such as updating an order status for the exact reason you've asked the question. Therefore, when you query the order in the DB, it would still be marked as unpaid, and then you can put in the appropriate response.

Validating the order is what the notify_url is for (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ for more information). Basically, this does a checkback to paypal to confirm that the order you have attempted to make has actually gone through successfully, and then you do your DB updates (setting the order to complete).

The solution for you would be to remove the 'order updating' functionality from the return_url, and implement the IPN.